# 2 buttons next to each other width margins with css

Tags: html, css

How do I put these `<a>`'s in the center of the div, next to each other with 40px of space in between them inside of a 100% width div?

```css
a.explore {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #4f96b6;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a class="explore" href="#" target="_blank">I'm Ready To Go</a>
  <a class="explore" href="#" target="_blank">Take Me Somewhere</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok links, how do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using `display:flex` and `justify-content:center` on `#container`

```css
a.explore {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #4f96b6;
  font-size: 20px;
}
a.explore:first-child {
  margin-right:40px;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;

  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a class="explore" href="#" target="_blank">I'm Ready To Go</a>
  <a class="explore" href="#" target="_blank">Take Me Somewhere</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see the problem in your solution, it's not the most simple one, but it certainly works.

Comment: @Paulie_D you forgot to add `padding:1em` and `width:100%` to the second container `#container2` in your codepen example ................see here http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/BzYWPj  . they are the same

Answer (score 0):

These aren't buttons...they're links...there's a [**difference**](http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/).

However, flexbox is ideal here:

```css
a.explore {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #4f96b6;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #c0ffee;
}
a:first-child {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
a:last-child {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <a class="explore" href="#" target="_blank">I'm Ready To Go</a>
  <a class="explore" href="#" target="_blank">Take Me Somewhere</a>
</div>
```